# Android: I want a new activity to call new activity

Tags: android, listview, onclick

I made a main activity to call a new activity like this

```
public class Main extends ActionBarActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout);
    String[] item = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.main_list);

    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, item));
    list.setOnItemClickListener(this);

}

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos, long id){
    Intent intent = null;
    switch (pos){
        case 0 : intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), a.class); break;
        case 1 : intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), b.class); break;
        case 2 : intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), c.class); break;
        default: intent = null;
    }

    if(intent != null) startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

I succeeded call a new activity, called 'a'.

But, when I tried to call another new activity from 'a', I failed with same code what I did in Main.
What was problem?

a.class

```
public class a extends ActionBarActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout);
    String[] item = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.a_list);

    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.alist);
    list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, item));
    list.setOnItemClickListener(this);

}

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos, long id){
    Intent intent = null;
    switch (pos){
        case 0 : intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), aa.class); break;
        case 1 : intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ab.class); break;
        case 2 : intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ac.class); break;
        default: intent = null;
    }

    if(intent != null) startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

Specifically, after app launched, it crashes at clicking 'a' on the list

Comment: `But, when I tried to call another new activity from 'a', I failed. What was problem?` please explain more

Comment: Where is a.class code?

Comment: Can you provide a.java file code.

Comment: As I said, I did same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the activities on same intent object. instead of that create different objects for different classes. some thing like

```
case 0: Intent i1=new Intent(source, destination);
        startActivity(i1);
        break;
case 1: Intent i2=new Intent(source,destination);
        startActivity(i2);
        break;
   etc..........
```

or else create differnt object for different classes
one intent object for a,b,and c.
and second object for aa,ab and ac.